# Combine translation, alpha and scale animations in swift3

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, swift3, cgaffinetransform

I'm totally newbies with iOS Swift developement and i try to combine three parameters in a single animations but i don't succeed.

I think the solution is here -[Apple Dev Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW8) by grouping the animations but being a beginner and after a lot of Internet research i can't find what i'm looking for.

What do you think of my code and what is for you the best solution to combine performance and stability.

I want to point out that the purpose of this animation is to create an animated Splashscreen. There are other elements (UIImage) that will be to animates.

Here is my code:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    logoImg.alpha = 0
    logoImg.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -200)
    logoImg.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 0)

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 1.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {

        self.logoImg.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        self.logoImg.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
        self.logoImg.alpha = 1

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: The transform cannot be two different transforms. You are merely replacing one with another. You surely meant to combine them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on what I am seeing you are wanting to preset the animation and translate it back.  In that case I would do this.

```swift
self.logoImg.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -200).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 0))
self.logoImg.alpha = 0

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 1.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
    self.logoImg.transform = .identity
    self.logoImg.alpha = 1
}, completion: nil)
```

I think you may not be seeing all the animation so try to start the scale at 0.5

```swift
self.logoImg.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -200).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5))
self.logoImg.alpha = 0

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 1.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
    self.logoImg.transform = .identity
    self.logoImg.alpha = 1
}, completion: nil)
```

The key here is that the animation is animating back the original identity.  Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, i just see the scale effect, nothing on translation and opacity ! What i'm doing wrong!?

Comment: I really don't know. You don't have the view hidden in storyboard or code do you?

Comment: Do you have the opacity and alpha both at 0. They are different?

Comment: alpha is declared in viewWillAppear like this : logoImg.alpha = 0

Comment: Oh good way ! The scale and translations work fine but alpha not work! Yet I put the simulator into slow animations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `concatenating` method to combining two existing affine transforms.

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 1.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {

    let translation = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    let scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)

    self.logoImg.transform = translation.concatenating(scale)
    self.logoImg.alpha = 1

}, completion: nil)
```

Look at [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform/1455996-concatenating) for more info. Hope it help. :)

Comment: Thanks @luan-tran , but i don't see différence ! The scaleX work fine but nothing on translation or alpha.

Answer (score 2):

Rotate and Translate and make it like parallax effect in tableview header:

```
func setupTableHeaderView() {
    self.customHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, height: 200))
    self.customHeaderView?.backgroundColor = .white
    self.customImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, height: 200))
    self.customImageView?.image = ImageNamed(name: "camera")
    self.customImageView?.contentMode = .center
    self.customHeaderView?.addSubview(self.customImageView!)
    self.tableHeaderView = self.customHeaderView
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let yPos = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if yPos < 0 {
        let scaleX = ((yPos * -1) / 200) + 1
        let translateY = yPos / 2
        var commonTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        commonTransform = commonTransform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: translateY)
        commonTransform = commonTransform.scaledBy(x: scaleX, y: scaleX)
        self.customImageView?.transform = commonTransform
    }else{
        self.customImageView?.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }
}
```

NOTE : Make sure the View you apply transform to is SUBVIEW of the header view, not header view itself. In above example customImageView is subview of main headerview.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also with swift 3.0.1:

```
UIView.transition(with: self.imageView,
          duration:0.5,
          options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
          animations: { self.imageView.image = newImage },
          completion: nil)
```

Reference: https://gist.github.com/licvido/bc22343cacfa3a8ccf88