# UIView animations with scale and alpha

Tags: swift, animation, uiview, scale, alpha

I need make animation to show/hide view (UIButton), so alpha changes from 0 to 1 same time as scale of view changes from 0 to 100% (showing) and reverse (hiding). Each animation I can do separately but how make it together? And It must showing/hiding correct when user randomly (and may be so fast, for example, hiding animation not finished - showing animation starts) interact. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: maybe this article can help

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42710220/6202732)

Comment: Yes, I've read this article, but there is no my case "scale + alpha animation". And there is discussion about only appearing method, as I've said I need both - appear and disappear, which will be triggered randomly

Comment: This is easy to do, so how can we help you if you don't show us the code that isn't working and explain what you're trying to do and what happens instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

continuing the previous comments, I try to make a simple example.
so maybe the trick is in the transform "identity" which functions to restore the view to its origin, hopefully it helps

[image]

```
@IBAction func showButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.5, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {
       self.yourView.transform = .identity
       self.yourView.alpha = 1

   }, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func hideButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.5, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
       self.yourView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 0.7, y: 0.7)
       self.yourView.alpha = 0
   })
}
```

Comment: My bad, tried almost same code, but scaled to 0 when hide button, so there were no any animation.. Thanks!